# Using base R, how can I set parameters to define people who died on the titanic if the csv file only has a column for survived (0,1) and not deaths?

Tags: r, data-science, data-wrangling

This is how I've set it up the proportions to define the children who survived to later use in a bargraph. How can I wrangle this data to define the missing value of deaths?

```
propCS <- matrix(, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
dataChildren <- data[data$Age > 18,]
dataMale <- dataChildren[dataChildren$Sex == "male",]
dataFirst <- dataMale[dataMale$Pclass == "First", ]
dataSecond <- dataMale[dataMale$Pclass == "Second", ]
dataThird <- dataMale[dataMale$Pclass == "Third", ]

propCS[1,1] <- sum(dataFirst$Survived) / length(dataFirst$Survived)
propCS[2,1] <- sum(dataSecond$Survived) / length(dataSecond$Survived)
propCS[3,1] <- sum(dataThird$Survived) / length(dataThird$Survived)

dataFemale <- dataChildren[dataChildren$Sex == "female",]
dataFirst <- dataFemale[dataFemale$Pclass == "First", ]
dataSecond <- dataFemale[dataFemale$Pclass == "Second", ]
dataThird <- dataFemale[dataFemale$Pclass == "Third", ]

propCS[1,2] <- sum(dataFirst$Survived) / length(dataFirst$Survived)
propCS[2,2] <- sum(dataSecond$Survived) / length(dataSecond$Survived)
propCS[3,2] <- sum(dataThird$Survived) / length(dataThird$Survived)
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the data and expected output: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You cannot by just looking at the survived data, but it looks like you are asking about the "Titanic" dataset that is part of the datasets package, correct?

If so, it has 4 dimensions 1: Class, 2: Sex, 3: Age, 4: Survived each with their own set of levels. It looks like you want to get the proportion that survived for each combination, correct? If so, you can do the following:

```
data(Titanic)

survival <- data.frame(Class = c(), Sex = c(), Age = c(), Survived = c(), Died = c(),
                       Prop.Survived = c())
dnames <- dimnames(Titanic)
classes <- dnames$Class
sexes <- dnames$Sex
ages <- dnames$Age
for (cl in seq_along(classes)) {
  for (s in seq_along(sexes)) {
    for (a in seq_along(ages)) {
      survived <- Titanic[cl, s, a, "Yes"]
      died <- Titanic[cl, s, a, "No"]
      
      survival <- rbind(survival, list(
        Class = classes[[cl]], 
        Sex = sexes[[s]],
        Age = ages[[a]],
        Survived = survived,
        Died = died,
        Prop.Survived = ifelse((survived + died) == 0, NA, survived/(survived + died))
        ))
    }
  }
}
```

You can aggregate and plot using the aggregate and plot functions:

```
age_class <- aggregate(cbind(Survived, Died) ~ Age + Class, data = survival, FUN = sum)
sex_class <- aggregate(cbind(Survived, Died) ~ Sex + Class, data = survival, FUN = sum)

barplot(Survived/(Survived + Died) ~ Age + Class, data = age_class)
```